# Perl: extract subtring to end of file

Tags: regex, perl, substring

I want to extract a substring between some given word and the end of the file, I'm not having much luck though.

This is what my file looks like

```
non important line a
non important line b
...
...
...
non important line n
keyword
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

I want to match from the keyword to the end of the file:

```
keyword
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

I tried this which only replace the keyword with foo, rather than everything from the keyword to the end of the file:

```
cat foo | perl -pi -e 's/keyword.*\Z/foo/g'
```

Thanks !

Comment: `.` (dot) doesn't match newline by default. Add the [`s` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/keyword.*\Z/foo/sg'
```

`-0777` slurps whole file at once into `$_`, otherwise file would be red line by line into `$_`.

`/s` modifier on the other hand only tells regex that `.` should also match `\n` since we also want to match newlines when doing substitution on `$_`

Comment: Thanks, works a treat. According to the doc, -0777 causes the file to be treated as a single line, and so so the s modifier, why are both required though ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `s` modifier to treat newlines as normal characters

```
cat foo | perl -pi -e 's/keyword.*\Z/foo/gs'
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't work. It simply replaces the keyword with foo and removes the newline after the keyword.